# Facebook Profile Visitors Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way defined in the graph api for facebook to determine the number of profile visitors and there users ids ?
I  could not find a way defined in graph api or the facebook legacy api
Please let me know if anyone know such a way or an end point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short
**NO!**
Facebook doesn't provide such information for privacy reasons. You cannot also view profile visitors directly via facebook.com. If an app claims to do so, it's totally **false**.

Here's the official answer >> https://www.facebook.com/help/369078253152594

> No. Facebook doesn't let you track who views your profile or your posts (ex: your photos). Third-party apps are also unable to do this.
>
> If you come across an app that says it can show you who's viewing your profile or posts, please report the app.